# Javascript wont work on Timer_Tick method on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a Timer that ticks every 2 seconds and gets the percent value that constantly changes, this works fine when it displays in a label. I want to the same thing but to display in a message box using javascript, this display fine for the first time but when the value changes the value in the alert pop up remains the same.

```
protected void TimerProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        percent = max_time.PercentGoalMetToday(i.ToString());  
        lbPercent.Text = percent; //WORKS
        JavaScriptMethod();
    }

    protected void JavaScriptMethod()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("function main(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(percent);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("var myVar = setInterval(function () { main() }, 4000);");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
    }
```

ASPX

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelProgressBar" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblPercent" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="Percent"></asp:Label>  
   </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer" Interval="2000" runat="server" OnTick="TimerProgress_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
```

Comment: How is this server-side timer updating the client-side context?

Comment: In an update panel on the ASPX page.

Comment: @Apollo, then that's why the JavaScript stays the same. It's not inside the update panel.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud JS does not work with update panels.

Comment: @Apollo, I'm not saying you couldn't change some JavaScript with an `UpdatePanel`, I'm just saying that the JavaScript that's inserted with `RegisterClientScriptBlock` isn't going to get updated with an `UpdatePanel` because it's not *inside the `UpdatePanel`.* The idea of the `UpdatePanel` is that you get new HTML for the markup *inside* the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Would it not be possible to have a `WebMethod` which you can call from JavaScript through Ajax which gives you the percentage?

Comment: I have javascript Gage that needs the percent and it updates every 2 seconds. It does not refresh. The label refreshes fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this with SignalR which is designed for letting your server exchange data with browsers efficiently and in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work just change ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock to ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and it refreshes.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp", sb.ToString(), false);
```